# In latex, how to type a math symbol that is an equal sign with a dot in the middle?

Tags: math, compilation, latex

[image: equal sign]

The symbol is showed in picture above.

plus, I want to know How to type '>' with a dot in the middle like the one in the following picture
[image]

I have tried '\cdoteq' but failed.

Comment: You might get (better) answers if you repost this to https://tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\equaldot}{\mathrel{=\hskip-0.64em\cdot\hskip0.15em}}

\begin{document}

\[
  a \gtrdot b
\]

\[
  a \equaldot b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\[
  a \succdot b
\]

\[
  a \eqcirc b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]