# Is there a Unicode that a dot inside the equal symbol?

Tags: unicode, latex, symbols

[dotequal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqN6i.png)
I need this symbol. I've searched for it but can't find its unicode. All I can find is ≐ ,≑ and ≖, but what I need is a dot inside the equal, not above or around or a ring inside.

Here is its latex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\equaldot}{\mathrel{=\hskip-0.64em\cdot\hskip0.15em}}

\begin{document}

\[
  a \equaldot b
\]

\end{document}
```

from
[In latex, how to type a math symbol that is an equal sign with a dot in the middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557843/in-latex-how-to-type-a-math-symbol-that-is-an-equal-sign-with-a-dot-in-the-midd)

If there isn't such a Unicdoe, is there a way to combine two symbols = and · together?
That's to say, is there a way to make two Unicode stack together?

Comment: I'm not sure how useful it is to quote a complete made up name for a latex macro. Nobody knows what it is, if you don't also copy how this made up macro is defined.

Comment: Where do you want to use this symbol? Maybe whatever tool you want to use can do similar tricks with kerning.

Comment: I'm just curious about this symbol and wasn't certianly using it somewhere. It appears in my compiler classes. The stack I thought isn't depend on a certain tool, it should be Unicode's tricks L҈i҈k҈e҈ ҈T҈h҈i҈s҈

Comment: I do not find it. There are various *equal with dots*, but none in the middle (maybe it is shown as "variant" with VS0, but I didn't find it). In any case some useful charts: https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf, https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2A00.pdf and the index with this two files, and other maths operators, etc.: https://www.unicode.org/charts/

Answer (score -1):

You can define that symbol on your own. Here's a possible solution:

```
\newcommand*{\defeq}{\def\arraystretch{0}\begin{array}{c}
\overline{\underline{\,.\,}}
\end{array}}
```